# Determine if a string contains any specified values

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to do something like the following in jQuery:

```
if($('UploadField').val().contains('.gif','.jpeg','.jpg','.png'))
{

}
```

...checking for an array of values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if ($('UploadField').val().match(/\.(gif|jpeg|jpg|png)/))
{

}
```

should work

Comment: Since you are suggesting regular expressions, adding case-insensitive switch ("i") makes it match uppercase extensions, too. Also an end-of-line ("$") prohibits the likes of "file.jpg.exe".